# Can etale $X$-schemes be lifted to $Y$, where $X$ is closed in $Y$?  

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, sheaf-theory

For a closed embedding (of varieties) $X\to Y$ let $U/X$ be etale. Is is true that there necessarily exists an etale $U'/Y$ such that $U'_X=U$? If this is wrong in general, are there any assumptions that make the statement correct ('my' $X$ is smooth, for example) or any ways to 'repair' it (in particular, I am interested in simplicial schemes).

I need this statement in order to prove my 'conjecture' [Does one need to sheafify when defining the inverse image of a sheaf with respect to an embedding?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75580/does-one-need-to-sheafify-when-defining-the-inverse-image-of-a-sheaf-with-respect)
The 'topological' case of my current question is trivial (for manifolds or metric spaces, at least), yet I do not understand what happens in the \'etale setting at all. Certainly, I would also be deeply grateful for any response to my previous question.:)

Upd. Now I also suspect that I need etale tubular neighbourhoods here. Yet any alternative suggestions could be very welcome!

Comment: You probably mean "let $U/X$ be étale".

Comment: Mikhail, I'll assume the correction suggested by Matthieu, but then
it isn't true. Take $Y=\mathbb{P}^2$ and $X\subset Y$ a smooth elliptic curve. Any etale cover induced from $Y$ is trivial, but the fundmental
group of $X$ is large. You probably want some sort of tubular neighbourhood, but getting this in algebraic geometry seems tricky.
If you know Marc Levine, you might ask him. I think he has some version of this, but I haven't seriously looked at it. 

Comment: There is also some old work of Cox in the simplicial scheme setting,
which maybe worth looking at as well.

Comment: Such a statement is true Zariski locally.  See EGA IV, Proposition 18.1.1.

Comment: @Donu: Note that the extension is not required to be a *finite* étale map.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!! I probably need etale tubular neighbourhoods anyway (though it would be interesting to understand all alternatives here); I will also look at the references mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps you can add SGA2, exposé X to the references.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the topological version of this is also untrue, with the same counterexample and reason.

Comment: By the 'topological situation' I meant lifting open subsets from closed submanifolds. Yet note that a tubular neighbourhood of $X$ in $Y$ has the same fundamental group as $X$, so one definitely does not obtain a counter-example this way.